# What are the equations (Gen, Enc, Dec) for the vigenere cipher?

Tags: classical-cipher, vigenere

Long story short, trying to understand how I would write the vigenere cipher mathematically when using Gen, Enc, Dec and I can't figure it out. This is what I've come up with so far.

$$\mathrm{Gen}: k ={0…25}^t$$

$$\mathrm{Enc}: c_i = (p_i + k_i) \pmod {26}$$

$$\mathrm{Dec}: p_i = (c_i – k_i) \pmod {26}$$

It doesn't really seem right though, so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I'd change it is to make it explicit that $k$ is sampled from that set rather than is equal to it and to note that the key is used cyclically:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Gen}:&&k\leftarrow \{0,\ldots,25\}^t\\
\mathrm{Enc}:&&c_i=p_i+k_{i\pmod t}\pmod{26}\\
\mathrm{Dec}:&&p_i=c_i-k_{i\pmod t}\pmod{26}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: [Retracted] Does $\gets$ unambiguously mean sampled from? I tend to use $\overset{\$}\gets$ for this, and use $\gets$ for affectation, where some language like Pascal use `:=` in order to distinguish from the comparison operator. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @fgrieu Certainly not unambiguously. Galbraith omits the dollar sign in [his book](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/notation.pdf). Katz and Lindell tend to just say "Choose". Boneh uses $R$ instead of dollar and specifies uniformity. I dislike the dollar sign for TeX reasons, but it is widespread.

Comment: I checked standard references and you are right, my usage is kinda marginal. Plus I discovered the hard way that `\$` [causes trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369908/184379) in the rendering. So in the end I propose$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Gen}:&&k\gets\{0,\ldots,25\}^t\\
\mathrm{Enc}:&&c_i=p_i+k_{i\bmod t}\bmod{26}\\
\mathrm{Dec}:&&p_i=c_i-k_{i\bmod t}\bmod{26}
\end{eqnarray*}$$ with `\bmod`rather than `\pmod`, because only the former is an operator, and insures the outcome is in $[0,t)$ or $[0,26)$.